# Check for value in list

Tags: c#

I've got a generic list of values.  I want to check to see if an Id exists in that generic list.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

example

```
List<someCustomObject> mylist = GetCustomObjectList();

int idToCheckFor = 12;
```

I want to see if 12 exists in any of the custom objects in the list by checking each someCustomObject.Id = idToCheckFor

If a match is found, I'm good to go and my method will return a bool true.  I'm just trying to figure out if there's an easy way instead of looping through each item in the list to see if idToCheckFor == someCustomObject.id and setting a variable to true if a match is found.  I'm sure there's got to be a better way to go about this.

Comment: So yes I'm going with the LINQ option.  But if I were to loop, I guess what, the best way would be to set a bool var to false...and then set it to true when it finds a match and exit out of the loop when it does find the match and return the bool var.

Comment: @coffee: If you were looping, the easiest option would be to `return true;` from within the loop if you found it, then `return false;` after the loop has completed.

Comment: For the loop option ... foreach(someCustomObject checkObject in mylist) { if (checkObject.Id == idToCheckFor { return true; } } return false;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5, this is easy using LINQ to objects:

```
return myList.Any(o => o.ID == idToCheckFor);
```

Aside from that, looping through is really your only option.

Comment: Hi Adam .. better query than my version :) (+1), can u point me towards some good linq to objects resources, that would be helpful, Thanks ! :)

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga: Check out the book C# In Depth.

Comment: @Mahesh: The single most helpful resource would be the MSDN page on the `Enumerable` static class, since it exposes the LINQ-to-objects extension methods.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Boolean b = myList.Find(obj => obj.id == 12) != null;
```

Comment: If you're in 3.5 (which you would need to be to use a lambda), why not use the LINQ method rather than something specific to `List<T>`?

Comment: You don't need .net 3.5 to use a lambda. It's a compiler feature. I use lambas all the time when writing .Net 2.0 code with VS2008. It produces rather clean code with native List<T> methods.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ makes life easier

```
mylist.Where(x => x.id == idToCheckFor).Any()
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry my bad .. don't know what i was thinking .. thnks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong data structure for this. What you need is:

```
Dictionary<int, someCustomObject> myDictionary = GetCustomObjectDictionary();
```

Now you can easily check if the ID exists with fantastic performance.

```
return myDictionary.ContainsKey(idToCheckFor);
```

Comment: This is a difficult assessment to make since you don't know what else he is using the data structure for.

Comment: The dictionary is the way to go if you have a large list of objects, and need to search multiple times.

Comment: It's entirely possible that a `Dictionary` is the appropriate data structure, but you are making the assumption that the identifiers are unique. This is likely, but not certain.

Comment: Yes and you have the ValueCollection which offers much of the same functionality as a List. This means you can have the best of both worlds without having to use LINQ.

Comment: Well, I inferred from the question that he expects the items to have unique IDs. Wouldn't be very good IDs if they weren't unique.

Comment: @Chaos: Yes, assuming that a) ID's are unique, and b) the added complexity of a hashtable provides a meaningful performance boost. If this data is rarely queried, then a hash table is a needless cost. I would **not**, however, say that a `Dictionary` exposes the same functionality as a `List` simply because it has the `ValueCollection` property.

Comment: @Chaos: SSN's are generally good identifiers, but are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I didn't say it exposes the same functionality. It has ICollection and IEnumerable which are 2 of the List interfaces I use most.

Comment: the data structure is and will be a generic list.  I'm not willing to create another object (dictionary) JUST to be able to do a find easier.

Comment: Well if this is commonly used functionality this may show itself as a choke point later on. Especially if your list gets very large.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool found = mylist.Any(p => p.Id == idToCheckFor);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool bExists = myList.Any(x=>x.id == idToCheckFor);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mylist.Any(Item => Item.Id == idToCheckFor))
{
  do();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

return myList.Exists(item => item.Id == idToCheckFor);

For linq resources you can check [101 linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use LINQ to Objects.  Something like the following:

```
var result = from l in mylist
             where l.id = 12
             select l;

return result != null;
```

Comment: -1. `result` is a query, *not* an object. It would never be null.

Comment: Also `=` is an assignment operator, not an operator to test for equality.